# Are there any time-based events in Pillars of Eternity?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Is anything in the game based on time elapsed (except for the obvious stronghold build-times)? Can passage of time change the epilogue, influence quest outcomes etc?

It would seem that, when I can afford it, it would be prudent to just build my Stronghold as much as I can doing nothing but sleeping. Would there be any downside to that decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hirelings need to get paid

Once you have a barracks, you can pay hirelings to hang out at the stronghold, providing small adjustments to prestige and security. If you are ever raided by bandits, the hirelings will assist your party in the fight.

Hirelings are paid every five in-game days, so make sure that you have enough copper to cover their salaries before you start sleeping to rush your stronghold upgrades. This is mainly a problem earlier in the game, as by mid to late game you should have more than enough money to cover a few weeks of napping.

**You can of course also avoid this by not hiring any hirelings.**

[image: screenshot of hireling screen with wages]

Comment: There also seems to be a bug with the UI display where it always lists the hirelings as "Currently Unpaid" for every day that is not payday.

Comment: @Affine Yeah, i'm not sure if it's a bug or just really strange UI design. I was expecting to see some sort of total "you will owe X on the next payday" or "X wages owed so far". The little parchment and ribbon icon doesn't seem to do anything when clicked either.

Comment: This is all? No bad outcome will hapoen if for example I ignore the mothers plea quest for example 5 days?